# OpenedX url referencing

Tags: python, django, django-templates, edx, openedx

I am experimenting with adding an anchor tag in the file "course_outline.html" in the template folder of cms. I want the user to be redirected to another page on clicking this. For experimentation I am doing `<a href="<% url upload_transcripts %>".. >`.( Note that upload_transcripts is already defined in urls.py in the cms folder as `url(r'^transcripts/upload$', 'contentstore.views.upload_transcripts', name='upload_transcripts')`

)
This is giving an error. In particular the error page saying 'The studio servers encountered an error' and nothing else. Note that I have already tried `<a href="{% url upload_transcripts %}" .. >` with no success . Can someone help with this ?

Environment: Devstack version  in Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: "an error" - any particular one? Maybe you could tell us what the error is, so we can help you debug it?

Comment: only the error page comes up as added in the edit

Comment: this error occured in your production env or dev env ? which edx version are you using ? share these info

Comment: added version details

Comment: edx is using mako templates, i'm afraid this will be a syntax error and have you checked reverse function https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/urlresolvers/ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up created a new views.py and editing the urls.py. This seems to have solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

**open-edx** is using [mako templating](http://www.makotemplates.org/) its syntax is diffrent from [jinja templating](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/) , the error occured to you will be a syntax error.

You can use [reverse](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/urlresolvers/#s-reverse) function in django urlresolvers

try this

```
<a href="${reverse('upload_transcripts')}">${_('Redirect')}</a>.
```

dont forget to import it in your html

```
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
```